# Class variable in EJB 3 is thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, ejb

In servlet, because it's singleton except implement `SingleThreadModel`. Reference this article https://www.fortify.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/singleton_member_field_race_condition.html

But in EJB 3, I cannot find a similar document. And because container will create a pool to handle EJBs. I think the class variable should be safe, is it correct?

For example, `classVar1` is a class variable, I initial it in constructor and use it later. In servlet, it may have problem, but in EJB 3, it should be ok, right?

```
@Stateles
public class HelloBean implements Hello {

    ObjectXXX classVar1;

    public HelloBean() {
        ObjectXXX classVar1 = new ObjectXXX();
    }

    public String doHello(String message) {
        return message + classVar1.method1();
    }
}
```

And another question is that the resource (i.e. `EntityManager` in JPA) injected to EJB, it should be thread safe?

Answer (score 2):

The container must let only 1 thread in particular EJB instance, so: each method can be executed by only a single thread and your variable is 'safe' (as you initialize it in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` method).

**However**, the SLSB (stateless EJB) should **not** be used to keep a state. The EJB is pooled, so you don't have any guarantee that you will return to the same instance. The SFSB is made for this purpose.

The EntityManager, as every instance field in the EJB, is thread safe.

**However**, the EntityManager itself is **not** thread safe and cannot be used in environment where more than 1 thread can access it (i.e. in Servlet). `EntityManagerFactory` should be used instead in such cases.

Comment: correct me if i am wrong, EntityManager injected to ejb by application server IS thread safe, it is actually a proxy. however, this does not hold for CDI bean via @PersistenceContext

Comment: Yes, the container uses a proxy of the EntityManager, but I don't quite get the 'CDI bean via `@PersistenceContext'`. Do you mean the injection of CDI bean into an EJB using `@Inject` or the`@PersistenceContext` EntityManager injected into a CDI bean?

Comment: @Depeng you'e slightly wrong. The entity manager is NOT guaranteed to be thread safe. It might be in a particular implementation, but it's not required to be. A stateless or stateful EJB is what makes access to an injected entity manager safe, since those two are thread safe themselves.